# Accessing Arrays created Using Malloc

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

what is wrong with this?
why wont it work? its showing segmentation fault(core dumped)
Cant we use `a[I]`?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int *a,i,n;

  scanf("%d",&n);

  *a=malloc(n*sizeof(int));

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    a[i]=i;

  free(a);

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: should be a=malloc, drop the *

Comment: 1. Do a bit of indentation. 2. Turn on the compiler warnings. - The line `*a=malloc(n*sizeof(int));` is incorrect. 3. Check the return value of the `scanf` function

Answer (score 2):

Please enable compiler warnings; something should be screaming at you about:

```
*a=malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

This says:

1. Allocate some memory.
2. Assign that address to the integer pointed to by `a` (which is uninitialized and points to no known location).

`a` itself is still pointing nowhere in particular.

Then:

```
a[i]=i;
```

writes into that random space.

You want to say:

```
a = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 1):

`*a = malloc( n * sizeof(int) );` should be `a = malloc ( n * sizeof(int) );`

`malloc()` allocates the storage and returns a pointer to the first byte.

As `a` is pointer variable is should point to the address.

Where as `*a` is incorrect in this case, because `*` along with pointers is used for de-referencing.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the memory address pointed to by `a` to the address returned by malloc.  Since `a` is not yet initialized, you are setting an undefined part of memory to the address returned by malloc.

```
*a=malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

Instead, set the pointer itself

```
a=malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```